# javafx load sokoban file

Tags: java, file, javafx, fileloadexception

Can someone tell me what wrong with my code? I got an error when I tried to load the file into a `fileInputStream`

error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\zzxx\Desktop\netBean\hw3\Sokoban_draft\data\1.sok (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

code:

```
String filePath = new String("file:///C:/Users/zzxx/Desktop/netBeanhw3/Sokoban_draft/data/1.sok");

GridRenderer gamePane = new GridRenderer();

File sokFile = new File(filePath);

byte[] bytes = new byte[Long.valueOf(sokFile.length()).intValue()];
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sokFile);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
```

Comment: Do you have a "file:" drive containing a folder called "C:"?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to specify the file protocol. (file:///)

Just use the path name instead.

Comment: Bro, I said, you dont need the protocol. Use "C:/Users/zzxx/Desktop/netBeanhw3/Sokoban_draft/data/1.sok"